# Adding two integers represented by linked lists

Tags: c, linked-list

**The question I came across.**[image: Question]

**Here is what I have done so far**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
  int digit;
  struct node *next;
};

struct node *make_node(int num, struct node *head);
struct node *newNode(int digit);
struct node *sum(struct node *num1, struct node *num2);
void print(struct node *node);

int main()
{

  int a, b;
  struct node *new_nodeA1 = NULL, *new_nodeA2 = NULL;
  struct node *new_nodeB1 = NULL, *new_nodeB2 = NULL;
  struct node *res = NULL;

  printf("\nEnter no. of digits for your two numbers (separate with space)  ");
  scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
  int n1[a], n2[b];

  printf("\n\nEnter first non-negative integer to add:  ");
  for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
    scanf("%1d", &n1[j]);
  printf("Enter second non-negative integer to add:  ");
  for (int k = 0; k < b; k++)
    scanf("%1d", &n2[k]);

  /* for (int i = 0; i <= a - 1; i++)
    printf("%d\n", n1[i]);

    printf("%d\n", a); */

  for (int z = 0; z < a - 1; z++)
    {
      new_nodeA2 = make_node(n1[z], new_nodeA1);
      /*new_nodeA2 = newNode(n1[z]);*/
      if (new_nodeA1 == NULL)
    new_nodeA1 = new_nodeA2;
    }

  for (int y = 0; y < b - 1; y++)
    {
      new_nodeB2 = make_node(n2[y], new_nodeB1);
      if (new_nodeB1 == NULL)
    new_nodeB1 = new_nodeB2;
    }

  printf("\n");
  print(new_nodeA1);
  printf("\n");
  print(new_nodeB1);
  printf("\n")
  res = sum(new_nodeA2, new_nodeB2);
  printf("Result: ");
  print(res);
  return 0;

}

struct node *make_node(int num, struct node *head)
{

  struct node *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  if (temp == NULL)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Call of malloc() failed\n");
      exit(1);
    }

  if (head != NULL)
    head->next = temp;

  temp->digit = num;
  temp->next = NULL;

  return temp;

}

struct node *newNode(int digit)
{
    struct node *new_node = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->digit = digit;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    return new_node;
}

struct node *sum(struct node *num1, struct node *num2)
{
    struct node *res = NULL;
    struct node *temp, *prev = NULL;
    int carry = 0, sum;

    while (num1 != NULL || num2 != NULL)
    {
        sum = carry + (num1? num1->digit: 0) + (num2? num2->digit: 0);
        carry = (sum >= 10)? 1 : 0;
        sum = sum % 10;


        temp = newNode(sum);


        if(res == NULL)
            res = temp;
        else
            prev->next = temp;

        prev  = temp;

        if (num1) 
      num1 = num1->next;
        if (num2) 
      num2 = num2->next;
    }

    if (carry > 0)
      temp->next = newNode(carry);

    return res;
}

void print(struct node *node)
{
    while(node != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d->", node->digit);
        node = node->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

**My Output**

[image: Output]

My compiler does not give me any error. I tried debugging my `make_node` function but I cant catch the problem as to why my nodes are skipping certain digits.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots. Provide the text instead. Bitmaps are not apropriate to display plain text.

Comment: @Gerhardh the screenshots refer to the question and output only. My code is in text. This allows for a much cleaner representation of the question which makes it easier for the community to help.

Comment: ***Should not use any resources other than the textbook.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your linked list insert code is very broken.  For this style of list, you need to walk down the list from `head->next` until a `null` is found and insert there.  Instead, you are always replacing the `head->next` with your new `temp` node, thus breaking the list.

You can also add to the list backwards, making the newly added item the head each time and thus get around the traversal for add, but beware this will place your numbers in reverse order (which actually helps when you do your adding, so perhaps this is good too.)

Comment: Should I then include a `for loop` in `make_node` and traverse the list till my `head->next == NULL` and then add `temp->next = num`?

Comment: That is where I would start.  You already have to do this for your print statement so you can copy from known code.